# DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry insights (Performance)

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, rendering, gdi

I am refactoring some code that used `System.Drawing` classes and GDI in order to draw a complex map image. The image consists of  objects like lines and polygons. In order to clip the objects, we used a implementation of a clipping algorithm, that first checked whether the object is within the borders of a bitmap or not. If it was intersecting, the object got clipped.

We now want to draw the same map image with WPF methods. I am using `DrawingGroup`s to create the geometry drawings. `DrawingGroup`s offer the possibility of adding a `ClipGeometry`, like that:

```
 TileSize = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(tileOrigin, new Size(Width, Height)));
 mapDrawing.ClipGeometry = TileSize;
```

The result looks good, and I can "feel" no difference in performance. Problem is, I have a hard time to measure that. I can definitely say how long it took to clip the objects with our algorithm, but I can't measure what time is needed for the clipping with the `ClipGeometry`. I guess the clipping is done when the UI starts rendering the drawings.

My questions:

- How could I measure the time needed for clipping with WPF `ClipGeometry`?
- Does anyone know how exactly `ClipGeometry` does the clipping?

Thanx for your input!

Comment: Try to use Application Timeline https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn957934.aspx

Comment: Indeed, that is what i am doing. But i have a hard time pinning down when exactly the clipping via the ClipGeometry is done.... I think the Rendertimes are a little longer, but less CPU time is used as our clipping alorithm is not executed. But i am not 100% sure, as we are talking nuances here. That is why i was asking if anyone has more insights in the processing of a ClippingGeometry (Is it done by UI or Renderthread? After or before all drawings are processed?)... Anyway, thanx for your response!